# How to install VMware Player bundle in bash on Darwin Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, vmware, darwin

How do I install VMware bundle on Darwin Linux in Bash???

```
bash-4.4$ sudo ./VMware-Player-15.5.2-15785246.x86_64.bundle
Password:
stat: illegal option -- -
usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...]

Darwin 18.6.0 x86_64

-rwxr-xr-x@ 1  VMware-Player-15.5.2-15785246.x86_64.bundle
```

Comment: Darwin is different than Linux. On macOS, you need [VMware fusion](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/info/slug/desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_fusion/11_0), not VMware player.

Comment: You have a valid question, but you have posted to the wrong StackExchange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Mark would you please explain. For example, what is with the output I'm receiving? What does that mean? Is there something that I'm doing wrong, not doing or have forgotten to do?

Comment: You're trying to run a shell script meant for Linux systems, but you're on MacOS, so it won't work. You need to get a different VMware  product called VMware Fusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```js
$ sudo -s
# ./VMware-Player-15.5.2-15785246.x86_64.bundle
```